# CSS Keyframe not working on IOS devices (Chrome, Safari)

Tags: html, css

I've programmed this keyframe here:

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#wrapper div {
  -webkit-animation: slideLeft 4s;
  animation: slideLeft 4s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes slideLeft {
    from {
        -webkit-box-flex: 0;
        -ms-flex: none;
        flex: none
    }
    to {
        -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex: 1;
        flex: 1
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div>Test</div>
</div>
```

As you can see it works but not in Safari or iPhone (Chrome, Safari Mobile). Does anyone has an idea why? I don't have this problem on Android devices...

Comment: Indeed seems like a webkit bug. They weirdly support transitioning it though, so do you really need an animation? Because for what you are doing, [a transition](https://jsfiddle.net/jqy8k9bo/) seems enough and safer.

Comment: ran across similar issue with `keyframes`. Switched over to transitions, but there is a weird bug which causes a shudder if you use `transform-origin`. The reason I switched over to `keyframes` in the first place. Oh well...

Answer (score -2):

////////////////Note////////// add (webkit) before keyframes also available now after the amendment

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#wrapper div {
  -webkit-animation: slideLeft 4s;
  animation: slideLeft 4s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

 @-webkit-keyframes slideLeft {
    from {
        -webkit-box-flex: 0;
        -ms-flex: none;
        flex: none
    }
    to {
        -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex: 1;
        flex: 1
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div>Test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i try with you to get the result
 because I do not have ios device